# Insertion in Leaf table in SQL Server MDS is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services, master-data-management

I am using SSIS to move data from an existing database to an MDS database.
I am following the following Control flow;

1. Truncate TableName_Leaf
2. Load Data to stg

The second step has the following data flow:
1. Load data from source database (This has around 90000 records)
2. Apply a data conversion task to convert string datatype to Unicode (as MDS only supports Unicode)
3. Specify TableName_Leaf as OLE DB destination.

The step 1 and 2 are completing quickly, but the insertion to Leaf table is extremely slow. (It took 40 seconds to move 100 rows end to end, and around 6 minutes to move 1000 records.)

I tried deleting extra constraints from the Leaf table, but that also did not improve the performance much.

Is there any other way to insert data to MDS which is quicker or better?

Comment: Drop all indexes\constraints\pks and then make your insert(BULK INSERT), it suppose to be a lot quicker.

Comment: I dropped the constraints and indices. Where exactly do we specify the insert as Bulk Insert ?

Comment: To reiterate what sagi said more formally, read the MSDN article "[Optimizing Bulk Import Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx)" and its sub articles for many tips (Including disabling/dropping indexes and constraints).

Comment: This worked . Thank you. :)

Comment: No problem, just curious, how much time did it take with bulk insert?

Comment: for 90000, around 20 seconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a  **Table or view - fast load.** in OLE DB destination connection helped resolve the issue. I used a batch size of 1000 for my case and it worked fine.